# How to add Validate() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form:

```
<form method='post' id='registration'>
...
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

And a script which send the form via POST:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#registration" ).submit(function(event) {

        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get some values from elements on the page:
        var form = $(this);
        var username = form.find( "input[name='username']" ).val();
        var password = form.find( "input[name='password']" ).val();
        var url = "action.php";

        // Send the data using post
        $.post( url, {
              username: username,
              password: password
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have written Validate() function also. Where is the right place to add it and how?

Comment: i would look at using jquery.validate. its an amazing plugin

Comment: please share your validate function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally do it right before the post.

```
if (validate()) {
    $.post();
{
```

This requires your function validate() to return either false or true if the form is valid.

Comment: Thank you :) I found my mistake. I made the same but I forgot to close the if scope and there was an error. Now it works!

Answer (score 2):

@Rebirth is quite right.

@Nikolay Tsonev, Why don't you put

```
    var form = $(this);
    var username = form.find( "input[name='username']" ).val();
    var password = form.find( "input[name='password']" ).val();
    var url = "action.php";
```

into your Validate() function.
and it would just go like directly like;

```
event.preventDefault();

if (validate()) {
    $.post();
{
```